# HTML space in signature in Outlook or Thunderbird

Tags: html, outlook, space, signature

i wrote email signature for Outlook and Thunderbird. My problem is in signature and space line between "Digital Print" and "Bo Kalako! s.r.o.".
Email from Thunderbird with space  `<br /><p></p>` dosent work and text is without space in line. Pleas give mi tip or help. Many thanks!

```
http://jsfiddle.net/k2hzw78y/
```

or

```html
<font style="font-family:'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color:#333;">S pozdravem</font><br><br><br>
 <font style="font-family:'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color:#333;">
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="270" rowspan="2" style="border-right: 1px solid #333333;"><a href="http://www.go-digital.cz/"><img src="http://www.caj.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Testorange.png" width="253" height="78" border="0"></a></td><td width="15"></td>
    <td colspan="6"><font style="font-weight:bolder; color:FF6600; font-size:11pt;">Karel Holina</font><br /><font style="color:FF6600D; font-size:10pt; font-weight:;">Digital Print</font>
  <br /><p></p>
  <font style="color:#1F497D; font-size:10pt;"><a href="" style="color:#333;font-weight: bold; text-decoration:none;">Bo Kalako! s.r.o.</a><br>  <font style="color:#333;font-weight:; font-size:10pt;">adress: Komen 601/13, 500 02 Big City
</a><br>  <br<font style="color:#333;font-weight:; font-size:10pt;">mobil: +490 623 980 130</a><br><font style="color:#333;font-weight:; font-size:10pt;">e-mail: john.lou@bo-kalako.com</a><br> <a href="http://www.bo-kalako.com/" style="color:#FF6600; text-decoration:none;">www.bo-kalako.com</a></font>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="8"></td>
  
</table></font>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you put two BR instead of one BR and one paragraph?

```
<font style="font-family:'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color:#333;">S pozdravem</font><br><br><br>
<font style="font-family:'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color:#333;">
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="270" rowspan="2" style="border-right: 1px solid #333333;"><a href="http://www.go-digital.cz/"><img src="http://www.caj.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Testorange.png" width="253" height="78" border="0"></a></td><td width="15"></td>
<td colspan="6"><font style="font-weight:bolder; color:FF6600; font-size:11pt;">Karel Holina</font><br /><font style="color:FF6600D; font-size:10pt; font-weight:;">Digital Print</font>
<br /><br />
<font style="color:#1F497D; font-size:10pt;"><a href="" style="color:#333;font-weight: bold; text-decoration:none;">Bo Kalako! s.r.o.</a><br>  <font style="color:#333;font-weight:; font-size:10pt;">adress: Komen 601/13, 500 02 Big City
</a><br>  <br><font style="color:#333;font-weight:; font-size:10pt;">mobil: +490 623 980 130</a><br><font style="color:#333;font-weight:; font-size:10pt;">e-mail: john.lou@bo-kalako.com</a><br> <a href="http://www.bo-kalako.com/" style="color:#FF6600; text-decoration:none;">www.bo-kalako.com</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="8"></td>
</table></font>
```

Comment: Nice Matteo, thanks for hint. Now it works. But i have another question: Vertical alignment the whole text is not centered against the vertival line = how center this? *In Jsfiddle is center ok but in Thunderbird isnt.